# SQL Server restore a detach database

Tags: sql-server, database, restore, detach

Is it possible to restore a detached database (no re-attachement)?

There is a big database, but no diskspace is available to create a backup.
So, I was thinking to detach the database, copy it to another server.

This other server uses powershell scripts to restore the database.
Will this work with a detached database? I cannot re-attach it with this script. Just restore.

> Restore-SqlDatabase -ServerInstance $serverInstance -Database $myDb -BackupFile "detachedFile" -Credential $Cred

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Backup of a database is different format (.bak). The files you get in the detach operation: mdf, ndf data file format , ldf log file format are different formats.

[You can read about the formats](https://sqlbak.com/blog/sql-server-backup-bak-vs-sqb/). I have put the content below from the site for easier reference.

> Usually, database backup files with .bak extension contain data in the
> standard Microsoft Tape Format (MTF)  used by  Microsoft itself as
> well as many backup tools for the Microsoft Windows platform.
>
> Microsoft Tape Format is used while writing and reading data to and
> from removable storage devices during storage management or data
> protection operations such as data transfers, copies, backup and
> restore. In the case of SQL Server, MTF files contain data and log
> information (MDF and LDF files) necessary for restoring the database.
> The MDF file is the Main Data File or primary database data file, that
> binds all other files in that database together. The LDF is the Log
> Data File and it contains all log information and is crucial for a
> database restore process.

You cannot use Restore database command against mdf,ldf files. You need to use attach, detach approach for them to be available in another environment. As @Peter Smith suggested, you can use the powershell scripts to do the same.